# How to apply the divergence thereom in the plane

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to work a seemingly simple practice problem but I am having some confusion. The question asked to verify the divergence theorem in the plane for the vector field $$F=(xy)i+(2x-y)j,$$ where $C$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$.

I.e., I want to verify that

$$\int_{C} \bar F \cdot n\, dS = \iint_{Rxy} \nabla \cdot \bar F\, dA$$

The right hand side I computed the gradient to be $$y-1$$ and integrated over the triangle to be $$\frac{-1}{3}$$

But my issue now is with the other integral. I am confused about what a normal is in only the plane.

For example, I could split it into $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$ maybe with $n$ being $-j$ for$ C_1$ and $-i$ for $C_3$ and for $C_2$ it would be perpendicular to $y=1-x$.

But then I don't know about $dS$.

Overall my question is: How to make sense of the left integral in the plane, when it involves element of surface area, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plane, you should use $ds$ instead of $dS$. It is not infinitesimal surface area, but instead infinitesimal arc-length. So $ds = \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} \, dt$, where $\vec{r}(t)=\left<x(t),y(t)\right>$ is a parameterization of your curve $C$.

Comment: Thanks I will try that , is the -1/3 part correct though?

Comment: and what about the dotting with the normal part ?

Comment: Yes, I believe $-1/3$ is correct for that double integral. The normal is just the unit normal to the tangent line of the curve. It is the unit tangent vector rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: PS: Is this equivalent to finding the circulation of F around C?

Comment: I believe since you are using the "normal" component, it would be the "flux" of $\vec{F}$ over $C$. If you integrate the tangential component, that would be the "circulation".