# Circulation around a curve

Tags: calculus, physics, vector-analysis

in a previous question I had asked

[How to apply the divergence thereom in the plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732582/how-to-apply-the-divergence-thereom-in-the-plane)

About the divergence of $F=(xy)i+(2x-y)j$ where C is the triangle with verticies $(0,0)$ , $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

I did this and solved for $\frac{-1}{3}$

My question is now;

Is this$\frac{-1}{3}$ also the circulation of $F$ around $C?$ The reason I ask is because I find myself a bit confused with what circulation is. It seems like it is obtained by taking the line integral over C, which is why it seems to me the answer would be the same. To get a better understanding and such say F= velocity=v

is the integral $\int_{C} v \bullet n ds$ the angular velocity of a fluid, and $\int_{C} v \bullet dR$ the angular speed? Arent they same?

Im just feeling confused about this. Hopefully someone can help to clear this up.

Thank you

Comment: I would say that for circulation you integrate the tangent component of the vector field while for the flux you integrate the normal component of the field

Comment: So I could simply take my normal say n=(x,y) and form T=(-y,x) and just solve that?